# Native Media Player libraries for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, media-player, http-live-streaming

I need native client-side media player libraries that support HLS, I will be using them with Wowza.

I found https://github.com/viki-org/VKVideoPlayer. What are the other feasible options?

Answer (score 0):

the other for free is vitamio

https://www.vitamio.org/en/

and other one I know of is BrightCove but that won't let you to have your media on your own server and you have to use their cloud which was a downside for me!

https://www.brightcove.com/

note : Vitamio is not updated since last year so it is a little bit buggy and there is no good  doc or tuts on the net for it

Comment: Vitamio is not free for use in application.

Comment: it used to be  free